# Cant call azure api to get metric definition

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I am trying to get metric definition for resource using Azure rest api "https://management.azure.com/{resourceUri}/providers/microsoft.insights/metricDefinitions?api-version=2018-01-01".

But I get error response stating "metricDefinitions contains multiple copies of the extension api 'providers/microsoft.insights/metricdefinitions'".

Any idea what's wrong.

Comment: For what kind of resource you're trying to get the metric definition?

Comment: I tried for virtual machine and storage account but for both of them I got the same response.